# How did the new Mike know where the bodies are buried?

Tags: plot-explanation, living-with-yourself

In the 7th episode of *Living with yourself*, new Mike takes new Dan to the woods, and shows him the place where the original Dan (and others) are buried.

The clones only have memories up to the moment they put the originals to sleep at that spa place. Original Mike never took new Mike there (at least not to our knowledge). So, how could he possibly know this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the using the [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) we have to say that the original Mike must have told his clone about it.

Shortly after their first meeting, Mike and his clone go for a car trip together: The original Mike hides a small screwdriver and threatens that "he knows karate", while the clone Mike finds that he has no scar from the childhood -  this is exactly the same spot, to which new Mike and Dan go in the episode 7, hence it must been near the hidden graveyard.

Comment: We also know it's not that far from the spa, since old Miles returning from the forest and new Miles returning from the spa ran in to the same farmer. They could have visited after going to the spa for answers.